# Angular JS access input values based ng-model stored in a string

Tags: javascript, angularjs, arrays, mean-stack

So I managed to generate and import an html code like

```
<input type="text" ng-model="text1">
<input type="text" ng-model="text2">
```

and I obtained a String array containing the ng-models of all such inputs in an array from a `$http.post` request like

```
$scope.ngmods=['text1','text2']
```

how do I get the values of the inputs by manipulating the array elements?

Here is what I have tried :

```
{{ {{ngmods[0]}} }}
```

like i tried to get the value of in the array element and then again enclosed it in the `{{ }}` hoping the results would be the same as `{{text1}}`

Answer (score 2):

use `$parse` to evaluate the expression against scope.
create a custom filter with `$parse` to get the scope value from a string

```
.filter('parserFil',function($parse){
     return function(item,scope){
        return $parse(item)(scope); 
    }
})
```

in the html pass the current scope `this` from the html to filter

```
{{ngmods[0] |  parserFil : this}}
```

```js
angular.module("app",[])
.controller("ctrl",function($scope,$parse){

  $scope.ngmods=['text1','text2'];
  
  
})
.filter('parserFil',function($parse){
     return function(item,scope){
       return $parse(item)(scope); 
    }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl">
 <input type="text" ng-model="text1">
 <input type="text" ng-model="text2">
 
 {{ngmods[0] |  parserFil : this}} 
 
</div>
```

Comment: I see that this works on stack overflow, but not when I integrate it into my code. It does not display anything :(  I use v1.6.^. Think it might be 'cos of it? Thanks!

Comment: Can you Create a plnkr

Answer (score 0):

```js
angular.module('todoApp', [])
  .controller('TodoListController', ["$scope", 
  function($scope) {
    $scope.setValue = setValue;
    function setValue() {
        var list = [];
        list.push($scope.text1);
        list.push($scope.text2);
        $scope.ngmods = list;
    }   
  }]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="todoApp">
<div ng-controller = "TodoListController">
<input type="text" ng-model="text1">
<input type="text" ng-model="text2"  ng-blur="setValue();">
<span>{{ngmods[0]}}</span>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use ng-repeat & make sure html in under ng-controller
Example

```
<html>
<body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
<h1 ng-repeat="x in records">{{x}}</h1>
<script>enter code here
var app = angular.module("myApp", []);
app.controller("myCtrl", function($scope) {
  $scope.records = [
    "Amar",
  "Mhatre"
  ]
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```